# KeyBinding not working in Visual Studio Extension

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, vsix

The key binding is not working in my visual studio extension...
I can't find any solutions anywhere...
This is my .vsct file:

```cs
    <KeyBindings>
        <KeyBinding guid="EmmetVS" id="EmmetEnablerCommand" editor="guidVSStd97" key1="D" mod1="Control" />
        <KeyBinding guid="EmmetVS" id="AbbreviationExpanderCommand" editor="guidVSStd97" key1="0x09" />
    </KeyBindings>

    <Symbols>
        <GuidSymbol name="EmmetVS" value="{bafb16a2-0b68-4b07-8dce-c19f141bf8b5}">
            <IDSymbol name="ToolbarGroup" value="0x0001" />
            <IDSymbol name="EmmetEnablerCommand" value="0x0100" />
            <IDSymbol name="AbbreviationExpanderCommand" value="0x0102" />
        </GuidSymbol>
    </Symbols>
```

The first key binding is for Ctrl+D (will change it later but for now... (how do I have multiple modifiers? Ctrl + Shift + Alt + E ?))
And the second one is for Tab key.

This is my command class for the Tab:

```cs
namespace EmmetVS.Commands;

[Command(PackageIds.AbbreviationExpanderCommand)]
internal sealed class AbbreviationExpanderCommand : BaseCommand<AbbreviationExpanderCommand>
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(OleMenuCmdEventArgs e)
    {
        await VS.MessageBox.ShowWarningAsync("AbbreviationExpanderCommand", "Button clicked");
    }
}
```

I expected the command which is in the code above to be hit, but it wasn't.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/keybinding-element?view=vs-2022

Comment: @aybe You didn't help at all, because this is what I followed and if you payed attention there is even an error in the documentation (I posted an issue)

Comment: You're complaining about achieving multiple modifiers, it is explained in the docs...

Comment: @aybe that was just a sub-question.... my main complaint is that the command doesn't work as it should

Comment: When I face such problem, I tend to do this https://www.google.com/search?q=vsix+example+github then grep the projects to try understand what's possibly missing.

Comment: @aybe Ok now we're getting somewhere... Could you tell me what grep means please?

Comment: @aybe Also none of those repos had the <KeyBinding>

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples